# Powershell InitializeDefaultDrives Error always stops Team Build from performing a successful build

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, cmd, tfsbuild

Whenever we start up Powershell on any machine on our network we instantly receive the following error in the console 'Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'FileSystem' provider failed.'

The reason for this is that upon start-up Powershell attempts to map all the drives it can find to Powershell objects, however, for some reason our Ops guys have configured all our network drives to appear as 'disconnected' even though they are fully accessible.  Powershell sees these drives as 'disconnected' and throws an error. I've tried to get the Ops guys to change this but the behaviour seems to be set quite deeply in our infrastructure.

Under normal usage it isn't too much of an issue, however, we are trying to run a Powershell script (with Psake) as part of an automated build process via Team Build, and the error on start-up is picked up by the build process and causes our build process to only partially succeed, it's impossible for us to achieve a nice, green, successful build.

Our Psake-based Powershell scripts is kicked off from a simple batch file that looks like this -

```
cls
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "& \"%~dp0psake.ps1\"" %*
echo EXIT CODE - %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

This batch file is called from an Invoke-Process workflow object in TeamBuild with the standard output and error output mapped to stdout and stderr respectively.

I can see a few potential areas we might be able to solve this

1. Find a way to stop Powershell from performing the InitializeDefaultDrives operation
2. Filter out that specific error in the batch wrapper somehow but still pass genuine errors back up to the build process
3. Parse errors in the Invoke Process workflow object so that particular error doesn't cause a failure, but all other errors still each the build process.

Any help GREATLY appreciated! : )

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found I was missing some error checking after my call to Powershell so my batch file should have looked like this...

```
cls
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "& \"%~dp0psake.ps1\"" %*; if ($psake.build_success -eq $false) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }
echo EXIT CODE - %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```